# Could not find the main class

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to run a java program bundled in the jar named easyflow-gui.jar using cmd:

```
java -classpath "." -jar easyflow-gui.jar
```

The working directory is the directory containing all relevant libraries.

The content of the Manifest file of the jar file I am trying to run is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_32-b27 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: easyflow.custom.jgraphx.editor.SchemaEditor
```

The result of this attempt is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mxgraph/util/mxEventSource$mxIEventListener
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mxgraph.util.mxEventSource$mxIEventListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: easyflow.custom.jgraphx.editor.SchemaEditor. Program will exit.
```

Question: which one of the classes is actually not found: the mxEventSource$mxIEventListener or the main class easyflow.custom.jgraphx.editor.SchemaEditor ?

Edit 1:
I checked the folder and extracted the jars and I find both classes available (bundled into its respective jars in the working dir):

```
$ls easyflow/custom/jgraphx/editor/SchemaEditor*
easyflow/custom/jgraphx/editor/SchemaEditor$1.class
easyflow/custom/jgraphx/editor/SchemaEditor$2.class
easyflow/custom/jgraphx/editor/SchemaEditor.class
easyflow/custom/jgraphx/editor/SchemaEditor.java
$ls com/mxgraph/util/mxEventSource*
com/mxgraph/util/mxEventSource$mxIEventListener.class
com/mxgraph/util/mxEventSource.class
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify `"."`  for the classpath if you want to include a jar file, it has to be a colon-separated list of jar files or directories (or semicolon-separated, depending on the operating system). Try `java -help` to get a description of the command line options.

Also if I remember correctly `-jar` and `-classpath` do not work together, so you have to use `-classpath` alone and specify the main class explicitly.

Try something like

```
java -cp easyflow-gui.jar:foo.jar:bar.jar easyflow.custom.jgraphx.editor.SchemaEditor
```

... where `foo.jar` and `bar.jar` are the "other relevant libraries".

Comment: Thanks for that hint ! java -cp . easyflow.custom.jgraphx.editor.SchemaEditor is working finally...

Comment: not sure what I did, but cannot reproduce today. the only way I manged to specify all jars in a certain folder is to use the wildcard like this: java -cp "lib/*" classname

Answer (score 0):

If you read the exception properly, you will see that the cause of the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mxgraph.util.mxEventSource$mxIEventListener
```

You didn't include the jar file that contains the `com.mxgraph.util.mxEventSource$mxIEventListener` in your classpath. From a quick Google search, you will need jGraph library.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Somehow I dont know how to include it else than I did: specifying the class path to the folder where I am and placing the jar containing the the class into that directory...

Comment: why not just do `java -jar easyflow-gui.jar` and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

The default classpath is the current working directory.
So, if you already have the jar in your current working directory, you dont need to specify the classpath explicitly.

The following command should work

```
java -jar easyflow-gui.jar
```

Comment: Could you please explain which conditions have to be met to get it working like that !? I am still only able to have it run by specifying the class name, which should obviously not really necessary, since it is already set in the manifest.

Comment: The manifest should specify the application entry point which will run the program.

Comment: In your case,the application entry point in the manifest file seems to be the SchemaEditor class indeed. Is the error that you got while running this command different from the original reported error. It seems odd to me.